# DC++ adding hubs

Tags: software-installation

How should I add hubs in DC++ after installing it. It's completely different from how it used to be in windows. Kindly Guide me through the process so that I can start downloading stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Go to favorite hubs : View -> Favorite Hubs OR Press Ctrl+F 
Click "Add" button in the bottom left corner 
Enter details in the box thus appeared. 
[Click to see how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr7Sq.png)